# Creating Sticky Headers in a Horizontal-Scrolling Comparison Table on Mobile with HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am facing a challenge with a comparison table I'm working on, where I need the headers to remain sticky when scrolling horizontally on mobile devices. The table is designed to compare multiple items, and it's essential that the side panel headers stay visible, especially when users scroll through a large number of columns.

Here's the structure of my table:

```css
body {
  padding: 1.5em;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}

.table-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  min-width: 1110px;
}

.table-head {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.table-head th {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 22px;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.table-head th img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.table-content td {
  text-align: center;
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c4c7;
}

th {
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  padding: 8px;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

td {
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  padding: 8px;
}

td.price {
  color: #58c27d;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.icon-container {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.icon-container.yes {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="21" height="20" viewBox="0 0 21 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M4.54011 9.2929C4.14959 8.90238 3.51643 8.90238 3.1259 9.2929C2.73538 9.68343 2.73538 10.3166 3.1259 10.7071L8.1259 15.7071C8.53103 16.1122 9.19303 16.0948 9.5763 15.669L18.5763 5.66897C18.9458 5.25846 18.9125 4.62617 18.502 4.25671C18.0915 3.88726 17.4592 3.92053 17.0897 4.33104L8.79481 13.5476L4.54011 9.2929Z" fill="black"/></svg>');
}

.icon-container.no {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="21" height="20" viewBox="0 0 21 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1.54785 12V10H18.7855V12H1.54785Z" fill="black"/></svg>');
}

.btn, .btn-link {
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .table-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table-wrapper">
  <tr class="table-head">
    <th></th>
    <th>
      Title 1
    </th>
    <th>
      Title 2
    </th>
    <th>
      Title 3
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tbody class="table-content">
    <tr>
      <th>Item 1</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 2</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 3</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 4</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 5</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container no"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container no"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 6</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 7</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container no"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container no"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 8</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container no"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container no"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 9</th>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Price</th>
      <td class="price">1 €</td>
      <td class="price">2 €</td>
      <td class="price">3 €</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <td><a class="btn btn-md btn-primary w-full w-lg-auto" href="#">Order</a></td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-md btn-link w-full w-lg-auto" href="#">Learn more</a></td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-md btn-link w-full w-lg-auto" href="#">Learn more</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My aim is to make the  elements within the  sticky on mobile devices, so that they stay at the top of the screen while users horizontally scroll through the columns.

Here's a preview of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: amazon table]

Could anyone advise on the best way to achieve this using CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tudor, please test this answer on mobile resolution.

```css
body {
    padding: 1.5em;
    background: #f6f6f6;
  }

  .table-wrapper {
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    min-width: 1110px;
  }

  thead {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }

  thead th {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 22px;
    z-index: 100;
  }

  thead th img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }

  tbody td {
    text-align: center;
  }

  tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c4c7;
  }

  th {
    border: 0px solid transparent;
    padding: 8px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
  }

  td {
    border: 0px solid transparent;
    padding: 8px;
  }

  td.price {
    color: #58c27d;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .icon-container {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  }

  .icon-container.yes {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="21" height="20" viewBox="0 0 21 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M4.54011 9.2929C4.14959 8.90238 3.51643 8.90238 3.1259 9.2929C2.73538 9.68343 2.73538 10.3166 3.1259 10.7071L8.1259 15.7071C8.53103 16.1122 9.19303 16.0948 9.5763 15.669L18.5763 5.66897C18.9458 5.25846 18.9125 4.62617 18.502 4.25671C18.0915 3.88726 17.4592 3.92053 17.0897 4.33104L8.79481 13.5476L4.54011 9.2929Z" fill="black"/></svg>');
  }

  .icon-container.no {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="21" height="20" viewBox="0 0 21 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1.54785 12V10H18.7855V12H1.54785Z" fill="black"/></svg>');
  }

  .btn,
  .btn-link {
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .table-wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      overflow-x: scroll;
    }

    thead tr th:first-child,
    tbody tr th {
      position: sticky;
      width: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 24px;
      overflow: visible;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    tbody tr td {
      padding-top: 24px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<table class="table-wrapper">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Title 1</th>
      <th>Title 2</th>
      <th>Title 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 1</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 2</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 3</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 4</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 5</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container no"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container no"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 6</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 7</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container no"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container no"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 8</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container no"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container no"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 9</th>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Price</th>
      <td class="price">1 €</td>
      <td class="price">2 €</td>
      <td class="price">3 €</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-md btn-primary w-full w-lg-auto" href="#"
          >Order</a
        >
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-md btn-link w-full w-lg-auto" href="#"
          >Learn more</a
        >
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-md btn-link w-full w-lg-auto" href="#"
          >Learn more</a
        >
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: almost perfect. If you look in the Amazon Example, the Legend/thead is starting at same level with first table column. Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: @Tudor, I understand your question. It would be possible, if we remove first column and place sticky items into the first column and make it sticky. Just fyi, Amazon also did it in such way.

Comment: the <th> place as <span> or something within normal <td>? Or how you mean?

Comment: @Tudor, I updated my answer, it should work as you expected. Please test and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Is the following what you want to achieve?

**Explanation**: I took out the `position: sticky;` from `th` of the element named `.table-head` and the `th`, and applied it to the `.table-content th`, so it stays stuck and so the `.table-head` "floats" above it, and this under `600px`.

You can tweak around with the `left` value, to position the column(s), and the `margin`'s of the `.table-content th`.

```css
body {
  padding: 1.5em;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}

.table-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  min-width: 1110px;
}

.table-head {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.table-head th {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 22px;
  /*position: sticky;*/
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.table-head th img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.table-content td {
  text-align: center;
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c4c7;
}

th {
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  padding: 8px;
  /*position: sticky;*/
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

td {
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  padding: 8px;
}

td.price {
  color: #58c27d;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.icon-container {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.icon-container.yes {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="21" height="20" viewBox="0 0 21 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M4.54011 9.2929C4.14959 8.90238 3.51643 8.90238 3.1259 9.2929C2.73538 9.68343 2.73538 10.3166 3.1259 10.7071L8.1259 15.7071C8.53103 16.1122 9.19303 16.0948 9.5763 15.669L18.5763 5.66897C18.9458 5.25846 18.9125 4.62617 18.502 4.25671C18.0915 3.88726 17.4592 3.92053 17.0897 4.33104L8.79481 13.5476L4.54011 9.2929Z" fill="black"/></svg>');
}

.icon-container.no {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="21" height="20" viewBox="0 0 21 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1.54785 12V10H18.7855V12H1.54785Z" fill="black"/></svg>');
}

.btn,
.btn-link {
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .table-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
  }
  /*new code*/
  .table-head th,
  .table-content td,
  .table-content {
    position: relative;
    left: -300px;
  }
  .table-content th {
    position: sticky;
    margin-top: -14px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: -14px;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table-wrapper">
  <tr class="table-head">
    <th></th>
    <th>
      Title 1
    </th>
    <th>
      Title 2
    </th>
    <th>
      Title 3
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tbody class="table-content">
    <tr>
      <th>Item 1</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 2</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 3</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 4</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 5</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container no"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container no"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 6</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 7</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container no"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container no"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 8</th>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container no"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container no"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="icon-container yes"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Item 9</th>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Price</th>
      <td class="price">1 €</td>
      <td class="price">2 €</td>
      <td class="price">3 €</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <td><a class="btn btn-md btn-primary w-full w-lg-auto" href="#">Order</a></td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-md btn-link w-full w-lg-auto" href="#">Learn more</a></td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-md btn-link w-full w-lg-auto" href="#">Learn more</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @DavidThomas the <th> is sticky indeed, but it's still overlapping the table content. In the GIF (Amazon example), it's not only sticky, but also fixed (starts at the first column). You know what I mean?

Comment: @iorgv: yes, I hadn't noticed that OP had responded and mistook the author of that comment for you. My apologies!

Comment: I've fixed my code for it to be under `600px`.

Comment: But the Legend/Thead is overlapping the content, did you see?